# How to user MVC routing after Javascript callback response?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm sending a request to the server. After I get successful response I want to load partial page inside the current page.

I know that there is AngularJS Routing and MVC Rounting. Two different ways.

I know that I can use @Html.ActionLink in cshtml file to load another partial page. The problem is that I want to do it only in the case that I get a successful response from the server.

How can I do it?

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

@*@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1*@

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

@RenderBody()

---

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
    </script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

First page that loads into @RenderBody()

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
<div class="row">
    <span>Login</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label>User Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="username" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <button type="button" ng-click="login(username)">Enter Chat</button>
</div>
```

And this is the controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'Login'];

function LoginController($scope, $http, $compile, Login) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    $scope.username = null;

    $scope.login = function (_username) {

        //Move To Service
        var postUrl = '/api/Login';
        var postData = { username: _username };

        $http.post(postUrl, postData)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          RedirectToChatContentPage();
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        );

    };

    function RedirectToChatContentPage() {
        //Move to service
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Home/ChatContentView',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('div#container').html(response);
        });
    }
}
```

})();

Comment: Look into `@Ajax.ActionLink`. You'll need to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in your project to use it.

Comment: Not sure you need any kind of "routing" - The easiest option is to load the second content with an ajax call (jquery).

Comment: This is so old and convenient, is their a way to use angular?

Comment: We can't really help more since the question is vague. It would be helpful to see your view/controller code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used and it works for me:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Home/ChatContentView',
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function (response) {
    $('div#container').html(response);
});
```

Comment: This is why you need to post your code. You asked for an angular / .net MVC specific solution, so nobody is going to suggest a simple jquery ajax call.

Comment: I posted my code. My solution works but then the angular doesn't work...so this is a partial solution that not really a solution...I should use angular to load the partial page in order to get proper angular cycle.